# Prove that $\chi_l(K_{3,27})>3$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that $\chi_l(K_{3,27})>3$

I know that I only need to prove that $\chi_l(K_{3,27})=3$ then there exist a collection of color list such that this graph can't be properly colored. And I can use brute force to do it by letting the smaller partite has color lists $L(u_1) =(1,2,3), L(u_2)=(4,5,6), L(u_3)=(7,8,9)$.

For the bigger partite let $L(w_1)=(1,4,7),L(w_2)=(1,4,8),L(w_3)=(1,4,9),L(w_4)=(1,5,7),..., L(w_{27})=(3,6,9)$

I know that every vertex in the bigger partite has degree $3$, so eventually, there will be at least one vertex can't be colored properly, and I can check it one by one.

However, I wonder if there is a faster way to do this without using the brute force?

Here is part of the example of brute force

If $c(u_1)=1, c(u_2)=4, c(u_3)=7$ then $w_1$ can't be colored properly

if $c(u_1)=1, c(u_2)=4, c(u_3)=8$ then $w_2$ can't be colored properly

if $c(u_1)=1, c(u_2)=4, c(u_3)=9$ then $w_3$ can't be colored properly

so on and so on

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. You gave lists that show that $\chi_l(K_{3,27})>3$, since no matter what colors are chosen for $u_1$, $u_2$, and $u_3$, there will be a $w_i$ whose list consists of exactly those colors, and thus can't be colored properly. That's all there is to the proof.

Comment: @PerryElliott-Iverson yeah, I agree with you that we all can see that, that why I say we will have that vertex eventually, but my professor is an inquisitor, if I say something like that, I will get a big zero with a comment that say " how do you know you will eventually get this?" So the only way to avoid that zero is to check one by one and write down each of them

Comment: @bof before I use that property I need to prove it lately or it must be stated in my book, and none of those is valid for me at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Theorem.** $\chi_\ell(K_{n,n^n})\gt n$.

**Proof.** Let $U=\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ and $W=\{w_1,\dots,w_{n^n}\}$ be the partite sets of $K_{n,n^n}$.

Let $L(u_1),\dots,L(u_n)$ be disjoint $n$-element lists of colors. Let $\{T_j:1\le j\le n^n\}$ be the set of all transversals for the set-system $\{L(u_1),\dots,L(u_n)\}$, i.e., all $n$-element sets $T$ obtained by choosing one element from each list $L(u_i)$. Let $L(w_j)=T_j$.

Clearly, no coloring from this list assignment can be proper. This is because the set of colors used to color the vertices in $U$ will have to coincide with one of the lists $L(w_j)$.